# Does column order matter when defining unique constraints

Tags: postgresql

How is this

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    col3 DOUBLE PRECISION NULL,
    UNIQUE(col1, col2)
);
```

Different from this?

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    col3 DOUBLE PRECISION NULL,
    UNIQUE(col2, col1) -- reversed column ordering
);
```

From what I understand both commands will generate an index on the two columns to enforce the unique constraint but with different ordering.

So I would not need to generate a separate index to speed up queries like this in either case.

```
SELECT id, col3 FROM foo WHERE col1 = 'stack' AND col2 = 'overflow'
```

However if future queries will also involve querying by column "col2" alone like below the latter form is preferred because the index will still be usable right?

```
SELECT id, col3 FROM foo WHERE col2 = 'overflow'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The order matters if you expect to ever use the index as a partial index.  For example, suppose you had a unique index on `(col1, col2)`, and you wanted to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM foo WHERE col1 = 'stack';
```

The index on `(col1, col2)` could still be used here, because `col1`, which appears in the `WHERE` clause, is the leftmost portion of the index.  Had you defined the unique constraint on `(col2, col1)`, the index could not be used for this query.